# Telling right from left

Tags: ho.history-overview, big-list

I know a lot of people, some of them mathematicians, who have trouble telling right from left. This can lead to problems when you are composing functions, for example.

When did this seemingly innocuous confusion lead to wrong results being published? [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10726) is an example from arithmetic geometry.

Comment: This makes me wonder more generally about when conflicting conventions have lead to incorrect results.

Comment: it's a constant issue in group theory, how to evaluate compositions, from left or from right...

Comment: Per @Wojowu's musing:  signs!  See, for example, [Lawson - A note on sign conventions in homological algebra](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~tlawson/papers/signs.pdf).  (At least, that's the advertised title on Lawson's web page; the title on the linked page better describes the experience of those who have to deal with this sort of thing.)

Comment: actually, if we are talking about conventions, here is one amusing article about Hamiltonian vector fields: https://symplecticfieldtheorist.wordpress.com/2015/08/23/signs-or-how-to-annoy-a-symplectic-topologist/

Answer (score 7):

I don’t know about wrong results, but compare Godement’s *Algèbre* ([1966](//books.google.com/books?id=pW9GAAAAYAAJ&q=%22classe+%C3%A0+droite%22), and still 1980):

> on dit que l’ensemble $x\mathrm H$ est une **classe à droite modulo** $\mathrm H$

(translation: “we say that the set $x \mathrm{H}$ is a **right class modulo $\mathrm{H}$**”)

with everyone else, e.g. his associate Bourbaki ([1970](//books.google.com/books?id=4RIDPH1ULXcC&pg=SA1-PA33&dq=%22classes+%C3%A0+gauche%22)):

> les ensembles $x\mathrm H$, qu'on appelle ***classes à gauche suivant*** $\,\mathrm H$ (ou ***modulo*** $\,\mathrm H$)

(translation: “the sets $x \mathrm{H}$, which are called ***left classes following $\mathrm{H}$*** (or ***modulo $\mathrm{H}$***)”)

Comment: maybe you should include a translation (as a sidenote, it kind of annoys me when people use French excerpts in articles written in English expecting everyone to understand). My French tells me "droite" is "left" and "gauche" is "right" (or I am making the exact mistake we are talking about?).

Comment: but then the answer is not fully self-contained, it requires you to visit another website to comprehend it.

Comment: In English, "adroit" is skilful, adept, and "gauche" is unsophisticated and clumsy, so you can kind of guess which is which :-)

Comment: @schematic_boi Um, sorry to point it out, but you have just demonstrated one example of how mix-ups happen. Yes, droit also means a right (in law), so there are hints.

Comment: @GregT ah OK. I am not even a native speaker of the English language, so I guess it is OK for me not to know what droit means. My belief is that while the person giving an MO answer is not *obliged* to provide a translation, it kind of makes sense for them to do that, because it is easy for them, and how many other people will not understand what is written there and will have to use Google Translate? Probably more than one.

Comment: @schematic_boi Yes, you are right, translation would be good. No problem at all. Btw I thought the point of the question was HOW to tell left from right? Which would also make sense, and I don't know a good mathematical definition.

Comment: There seems to be no need to be coy.  My inexpert translation:  the first says "one says that the set $x H$ is a **right coset modulo $H$**" and the second says "the sets $x H$, which one calls **left cosets under $H$** (or **modulo $H$**)".

Comment: By the way, I always got tripped up by this (as I do by the question of which is the subobject and which is the quotient when one speaks of "an extension of $A$ by $B$"), but @BCnrd provided a nice mnemonic for at least being consistent, which is that a right coset modulo $H$ in Godement's terminology has a right action by $H$.

Comment: As a kid I was told by my mum who was my school teacher that $5×3$ was to be read "$5$ multiplié par $3$" hence $5+5+5$ and not $3+3+3+3+3$. I still don't accept this 30 years later.